# Multi POST query (session mode)

Tags: python, r, session, scrapy, httr

I am trying to interrogate this [site](https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/welcome) to get the list of offers. 
The problem is that we need to fill 2 forms (2 POST queries) before receiving the final result.

This what I have done so far:

First I am sending the first POST after setting the cookies:

```
library(httr)
set_cookies(.cookies = c(a = "1", b = "2"))
first_url <- "https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/submit"
body <- list(energy_category="electricity",
             location="home",
             "location-home"="shift",
             "retailer-company"="",
             postcode="3000",
             distributor=7,
             zone=1,
             energy_concession=0,
             "file-provider"="",
             solar=0,
             solar_feedin_tariff="",
             disclaimer_chkbox="disclaimer_selected")
qr<- POST(first_url,
          encode="form",
          body=body)
```

Then trying to retrieve the offers using the second post query:

```
gov_url <- "https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire/submit"
qr1<- POST(gov_url,
          encode="form",
          body=list(`person-count`=1,
                    `room-count`=1,
                    `refrigerator-count`=1,
                    `gas-type`=4,
                    `pool-heating`=0,
                    spaceheating="none",
                    spacecooling="none",
                    `cloth-dryer`=0,
                    waterheating="other"),
          set_cookies(a = 1, b = 2))
)
library(XML)
dc <- htmlParse(qr1)
```

But unfortunately I get a message indicating the end of session. Many thanks for any help to resolve this.

#### update add cookies:

I added the cookies and the intermediate GET, but I still don't have any of the results.

```
library(httr)
first_url <- "https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/submit"
body <- list(energy_category="electricity",
             location="home",
             "location-home"="shift",
             "retailer-company"="",
             postcode=3000,
             distributor=7,
             zone=1,
             energy_concession=0,
             "file-provider"="",
             solar=0,
             solar_feedin_tariff="",
             disclaimer_chkbox="disclaimer_selected")
qr<- POST(first_url,
          encode="form",
          body=body,
          config=set_cookies(a = 1, b = 2))

xx <- GET("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire",config=set_cookies(a = 1, b = 2))

gov_url <- "https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire/submit"
qr1<- POST(gov_url,
           encode="form",
           body=list(
             `person-count`=1,
             `room-count`=1,
             `refrigerator-count`=1,
             `gas-type`=4,
             `pool-heating`=0,
             spaceheating="none",
             spacecooling="none",
             `cloth-dryer`=0,
             waterheating="other"),
           config=set_cookies(a = 1, b = 2))

library(XML)
dc <- htmlParse(qr1)
```

Comment: You never actually sent the cookies to the server?

Comment: Oh you are but only in the 2nd query? And they look meaningless.

Comment: @hadley Yes. How I can do it in a good way ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

using a python [requests.Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object with the following data gets to the results page:

```
form1 = {"energy_category": "electricity",
         "location": "home",
         "location-home": "shift",
         "distributor": "7",
         "postcode": "3000",
         "energy_concession": "0",
         "solar": "0",
         "disclaimer_chkbox": "disclaimer_selected",
         }


form2 = {"person-count":"1",
"room-count":"4",
"refrigerator-count":"0",
"gas-type":"3",
"pool-heating":"0",
"spaceheating[]":"none",
"spacecooling[]":"none",
"cloth-dryer":"0",
"waterheating[]":"other"}

sub_url = "https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/submit"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post(sub_url, data=form1)
    r = (s.get("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire"))
    s.post("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire/submit",
           data=form2)
    r = s.get("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/offers")
    print(r.content)
```

You should see the matching `h1` in the returned html that you see on the page:

```
          <h1>Your electricity offers</h1>
```

Or using scrapy form requests:

```
import scrapy

class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'comp'
    start_urls = ['https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire/submit']

    form1 = {"energy_category": "electricity",
             "location": "home",
             "location-home": "shift",
             "distributor": "7",
             "postcode": "3000",
             "energy_concession": "0",
             "solar": "0",
             "disclaimer_chkbox": "disclaimer_selected",
             }

    sub_url = "https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/submit"
    form2 = {"person-count":"1",
    "room-count":"4",
    "refrigerator-count":"0",
    "gas-type":"3",
    "pool-heating":"0",
    "spaceheating[]":"none",
    "spacecooling[]":"none",
    "cloth-dryer":"0",
    "waterheating[]":"other"}

    def start_requests(self):
        return [scrapy.FormRequest(
            self.sub_url,
            formdata=form1,
            callback=self.parse
        )]

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata=form2,
            callback=self.after
        )

    def after(self, response):
        print("<h1>Your electricity offers</h1>" in response.body)
```

Which we can verify has the `"<h1>Your electricity offers</h1>"`:

```
2016-03-07 12:27:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/offers#list/electricity> (referer: https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire)
True
2016-03-07 12:27:31 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

The next problem is the actual data is dynamically rendered which you can verify if you look at the source of the results page, you can actually get all the provider in json format:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post(sub_url, data=form1)
    r = (s.get("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire"))
    s.post("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire/submit",
           data=form2)
    r = s.get("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/service/offers")
    print(r.json())
```

A snippet of which is:

```
{u'pageMetaData': {u'showDual': False, u'isGas': False, u'showTouToggle': True, u'isElectricityInitial': True, u'showLoopback': False, u'isElectricity': True}, u'offersList': [{u'offerDetails': [{u'coolingOffPeriod': 0, u'retailerUrl': u'www.peopleenergy.com.au', u'offerId': u'PEO33707SR', u'contractLengthCount': 1, u'exitFee': [0], u'hasIncentive': False, u'tariffDetails': {}, u'greenpowerAmount': 0, u'isDirectDebitOnly': False, u'basePrice': 1410, u'offerType': u'Standing offer', u'offerName': u'Residential 5-Day Time of Use', u'conditionalPrice': 1410, u'fullDiscountedPrice': 1390, u'greenPower': 0, u'retailerName': u'People Energy', u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000', u'contractLength': [u'None'], u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': False, u'greenpowerChargeType': None, u'tariffType': u'Time of use', u'retailerPhone': u'1300 788 970', u'isPartDual': False, u'retailerId': u'7322', u'isTouOffer': True, u'solarType': None, u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0, u'offerKey': u'1645', u'exitFeeCount': 0, u'timeDefinition': u'Local time', u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/peopleenergy.png'}], u'isClosed': False, u'isChecked': False, u'offerFuelType': 0}, {u'offerDetails': [{u'coolingOffPeriod': 0, u'retailerUrl': u'www.peopleenergy.com.au', u'offerId': u'PEO33773SR', u'contractLengthCount': 1, u'exitFee': [0], u'hasIncentive': False, u'tariffDetails': {}, u'greenpowerAmount': 0, u'isDirectDebitOnly': False, u'basePrice': 1500, u'offerType': u'Standing offer', u'offerName': u'Residential Peak Anytime', u'conditionalPrice': 1500, u'fullDiscountedPrice': 1480, u'greenPower': 0, u'retailerName': u'People Energy', u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000', u'contractLength': [u'None'], u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': False, u'greenpowerChargeType': None, u'tariffType': u'Single rate', u'retailerPhone': u'1300 788 970', u'isPartDual': False, u'retailerId': u'7322', u'isTouOffer': False, u'solarType': None, u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0, u'offerKey': u'1649', u'exitFeeCount': 0, u'timeDefinition': u'AEST only', u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/peopleenergy.png'}], u'isClosed': False, u'isChecked': False, u'offerFuelType': 0}, {u'offerDetails': [{u'coolingOffPeriod': 0, u'retailerUrl': u'www.energythatcould.com.au', u'offerId': u'PAC33683SR', u'contractLengthCount': 1, u'exitFee': [0], u'hasIncentive': False, u'tariffDetails': {}, u'greenpowerAmount': 0, u'isDirectDebitOnly': False, u'basePrice': 1400, u'offerType': u'Standing offer', u'offerName': u'Vic Home Flex', u'conditionalPrice': 1400, u'fullDiscountedPrice': 1400, u'greenPower': 0, u'retailerName': u'Pacific Hydro Retail Pty Ltd', u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000', u'contractLength': [u'None'], u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': False, u'greenpowerChargeType': None, u'tariffType': u'Flexible Pricing', u'retailerPhone': u'1800 010 648', u'isPartDual': False, u'retailerId': u'15902', u'isTouOffer': False, u'solarType': None, u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0, u'offerKey': u'1666', u'exitFeeCount': 0, u'timeDefinition': u'Local time', u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/pachydro.jpg'}], u'isClosed': False, u'isChecked': False, u'offerFuelType': 0}, {u'offerDetails': [{u'coolingOffPeriod': 0, u'retailerUrl': u'www.energythatcould.com.au', u'offerId': u'PAC33679SR', u'contractLengthCount': 1, u'exitFee': [0], u'hasIncentive': False, u'tariffDetails': {}, u'greenpowerAmount': 0, u'isDirectDebitOnly': False, u'basePrice': 1340, u'offerType': u'Standing offer', u'offerName': u'Vic Home Flex', u'conditionalPrice': 1340, u'fullDiscountedPrice': 1340, u'greenPower': 0, u'retailerName': u'Pacific Hydro Retail Pty Ltd', u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000', u'contractLength': [u'None'], u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': False, u'greenpowerChargeType': None, u'tariffType': u'Single rate', u'retailerPhone': u'1800 010 648', u'isPartDual': False, u'retailerId': u'15902', u'isTouOffer': False, u'solarType': None, u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0, u'offerKey': u'1680', u'exitFeeCount': 0, u'timeDefinition': u'Local time', u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/pachydro.jpg'}], u'isClosed': False, u'isChecked': False, u'offerFuelType': 0}, {u'offerDetails': [{u'coolingOffPeriod': 10, u'retailerUrl': u'www.commander.com', u'offerId': u'M2E30367MR', u'contractLengthCount': 1, u'exitFee': [0], u'hasIncentive': True, u'tariffDetails': {}, u'greenpowerAmount': 0, u'isDirectDebitOnly': False, u'basePrice': 1370, u'offerType': u'Market offer', u'offerName': u'Citipower Commander Residential Market Offer (CE3CPR-MAT1 + PF1/TF1/GF1)', u'conditionalPrice': 1370, u'fullDiscountedPrice': 1160, u'greenPower': 0, u'retailerName': u'Commander Power & Gas', u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000', u'contractLength': [u'None'], u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': True, u'greenpowerChargeType': None, u'tariffType': u'Single rate', u'retailerPhone': u'13 39 14', u'isPartDual': False, u'retailerId': u'13667', u'isTouOffer': False, u'solarType': None, u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0, u'offerKey': u'2384', u'exitFeeCount': 0, u'timeDefinition': u'AEST only', u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/commanderpowergas.png'}], u'isClosed': False, u'isChecked': False, u'offerFuelType': 0}, {u'offerDetails': [{u'coolingOffPeriod': 10, u'retailerUrl': u'www.commander.com', u'offerId': u'M2E30359MR', u'contractLengthCount': 1, u'exitFee': [0], u'hasIncentive': True, u'tariffDetails': {}, u'greenpowerAmount': 0, u'isDirectDebitOnly': False, u'basePrice': 1330, u'offerType': u'Market offer', u'offerName': u'Citipower Commander Residential Market Offer (Flexible Pricing (Peak, Shoulder and Off Peak) (CE3CPR-MCFP1 + PF1/TF1/GF1)', u'conditionalPrice': 1330, u'fullDiscountedPrice': 1140, u'greenPower': 0, u'retailerName': u'Commander Power & Gas', u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000', u'contractLength': [u'None'], u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': True, u'greenpowerChargeType': None, u'tariffType': u'Time of use', u'retailerPhone': u'13 39 14', u'isPartDual': False, u'retailerId': u'13667', u'isTouOffer': True, u'solarType': None, u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0, u'offerKey': u'2386', u'exitFeeCount': 0, u'timeDefinition': u'AEST only', u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/commanderpowergas.png'}], u'isClosed': False, u'isChecked': False, u'offerFuelType': 0}, {u'offerDetails': [{u'coolingOffPeriod': 10, u'retailerUrl': u'www.commander.com', u'offerId': u'M2E33241MR', u'contractLengthCount': 1, u'exitFee': [0], u'hasIncentive': True, u'tariffDetails': {}, u'greenpowerAmount': 0, u'isDirectDebitOnly': False, u'basePrice': 1300, u'offerType': u'Market offer', u'offerName': u'Citipower Commander Residential Market Offer (Peak / Off Peak) (CE3CPR-MPK1OP1)', u'conditionalPrice': 1300, u'fullDiscountedPrice': 1100, u'greenPower': 0, u'retailerName': u'Commander Power & Gas', u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000', u'contractLength': [u'None'], u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': True, u'greenpowerChargeType': None, u'tariffType': u'Time of use', u'retailerPhone': u'13 39 14', u'isPartDual': False, u'retailerId': u'13667', u'isTouOffer': True, u'solarType': None, u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0, u'offerKey': u'2389', u'exitFeeCount': 0, u'timeDefinition': u'AEST only', u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/commanderpowergas.png'}], u'isClosed': False, u'isChecked': False, u'offerFuelType': 0}, {u'offerDetails': [{u'coolingOffPeriod': 0, u'retailerUrl': u'www.commander.com', u'offerId': u'M2E30379SR', u'contractLengthCount': 1, u'exitFee': [0], u'hasIncentive': False, u'tariffDetails': {}, u'greenpowerAmount': 0, u'isDirectDebitOnly': False, u'basePrice': 1370, u'offerType': u'Standing offer', u'offerName': u'Citipower Commander Residential Standing Offer (CE3CPR-SAT1 + PF1/TF1/GF1)', u'conditionalPrice': 1370, u'fullDiscountedPrice': 1370, u'greenPower': 0, u'retailerName': u'Commander Power & Gas', u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000', u'contractLength': [u'None'], u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': False, u'greenpowerChargeType': None, u'tariffType': u'Single rate', u'retailerPhone': u'13 39 14', u'isPartDual': False, u'retailerId': u'13667', u'isTouOffer': False, u'solarType': None, u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0, u'offerKey': u'2391', u'exitFeeCount': 0, u'timeDefinition': u'AEST only', u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/commanderpowergas.png'}], u'isClosed': False, u'isChecked': False, u'offerFuelType': 0}, {u'offerDetails': [{u'coolingOffPeriod': 0, u'retailerUrl': u'www.commander.com', u'offerId': u'M2E30369SR', u'contractLengthCount': 1, u'exitFee': [0], u'hasIncentive': False, u'tariffDetails': {}, u'greenpowerAmount': 0, u'isDirectDebitOnly': False, u'basePrice': 1330, u'offerType': u'Standing offer', u'offerName': u'Citipower Commander Residential Standing Offer (Flexible Pricing (Peak, Shoulder and Off Peak) (CE3CPR-SCFP1 + PF1/TF1/GF1)', u'conditionalPrice': 1330, u'fullDiscountedPrice': 1330, u'greenPower': 0, u'retailerName': u'Commander Power & Gas', u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000', u'contractLength': [u'None'], u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': False, u'greenpowerChargeType': None, u'tariffType': u'Time of use', u'retailerPhone': u'13 39 14', u'isPartDual': False, u'retailerId': u'13667', u'isTouOffer': True, u'solarType': None, u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0, u'offerKey': u'2393', u'exitFeeCount': 0, u'timeDefinition': u'AEST only', u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/commanderpowergas.png'}], u'isClosed': False, u'isChecked': False, u'offerFuelType': 0}, {u'offerDetails': [{u'coolingOffPeriod': 0, u'retailerUrl': u'www.commander.com', u'offerId': u'M2E30375SR', u'contractLengthCount': 1, u'exitFee': [0], u'hasIncentive': False, u'tariffDetails': {}, u'greenpowerAmount': 0, u'isDirectDebitOnly': False, u'basePrice': 1300, u'offerType': u'Standing offer', u'offerName': u'Citipower Commander Residential Standing Offer (Peak / Off Peak) (CE3CPR-SPK1OP1)', u'conditionalPrice': 1300, u'fullDiscountedPrice': 1300, u'greenPower': 0, u'retailerName': u'Commander Power & Gas', u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000', u'contractLength': [u'None'], u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': False, u'greenpowerChargeType': None, u'tariffType': u'Time of use', u'retailerPhone': u'13 39 14', u'isPartDual': False, u'retailerId': u'13667', u'isTouOffer': True, u'solarType': None, u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0, u'offerKey': u'2395', u'exitFeeCount': 0, u'timeDefinition': u'AEST only', u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/commanderpowergas.png'}], u'isClosed': False, u'isChecked': False, u'offerFuelType': 0}, {u'offerDetails': [{u'coolingOffPeriod': 0, u'retailerUrl': u'www.dodo.com/powerandgas', u'offerId': u'DOD32903SR', u'contractLengthCount': 1, u'exitFee': [0], u'hasIncentive': False, u'tariffDetails': {}, u'greenpowerAmount': 0, u'isDirectDebitOnly': False, u'basePrice': 1320, u'offerType': u'Standing offer', u'offerName': u'Citipower Res No Term Standing Offer (Common Form Flex Plan) (E3CPR-SCFP1)', u'conditionalPrice': 1320, u'fullDiscountedPrice': 1320, u'greenPower': 0, u'retailerName': u'Dodo Power & Gas', u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000', u'contractLength': [u'None'], u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': False, u'greenpowerChargeType': None, u'tariffType':
```

Then if you look at the requests later, for example when you click the compare selected button on the results page, there is a request like:

```
https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/service/offer/tariff/9090/9092
```

So you may be able to mimic what happens by filtering using the tariff or some variation.

You can actually get all the data as json, if you enter the same values as below into the forms:

```
form1 = {"energy_category": "electricity",
         "location": "home",
         "location-home": "shift",
         "distributor": "7",
         "postcode": "3000",
         "energy_concession": "0",
         "solar": "0",
         "disclaimer_chkbox": "disclaimer_selected"
         }

form2 = {"person-count":"1",
        "room-count":"1",
        "refrigerator-count":"1",
        "gas-type":"4",
        "pool-heating":"0",
        "spaceheating[]":"none",
        "spacecooling[]":"none",
        "cloth-dryer":"0",
        "cloth-dryer-freq-weekday":"",
        "waterheating[]":"other"}


import json
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post(sub_url, data=form1)
    r = (s.get("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire"))
    s.post("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire/submit",
           data=form2)
    js = s.get("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/service/offers").json()["offersList"]
    by_discount = sorted(js, key=lambda d: d["offerDetails"][0]["fullDiscountedPrice"])
```

If we just pull the first two values from the list ordered by the total discount price:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(by_discount[:2])
```

You will get:

```
[{u'isChecked': False,
  u'isClosed': False,
  u'offerDetails': [{u'basePrice': 980,
                     u'conditionalPrice': 980,
                     u'contractLength': [u'None'],
                     u'contractLengthCount': 1,
                     u'coolingOffPeriod': 10,
                     u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0,
                     u'exitFee': [0],
                     u'exitFeeCount': 1,
                     u'fullDiscountedPrice': 660,
                     u'greenPower': 0,
                     u'greenpowerAmount': 0,
                     u'greenpowerChargeType': None,
                     u'hasIncentive': False,
                     u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': True,
                     u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000',
                     u'isDirectDebitOnly': False,
                     u'isPartDual': False,
                     u'isTouOffer': False,
                     u'offerId': u'GLO40961MR',
                     u'offerKey': u'7636',
                     u'offerName': u'GLO SWITCH',
                     u'offerType': u'Market offer',
                     u'retailerId': u'31206',
                     u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/globird.jpg',
                     u'retailerName': u'GloBird Energy',
                     u'retailerPhone': u'(03) 8560 4199',
                     u'retailerUrl': u'http://www.globirdenergy.com.au/switchon/',
                     u'solarType': None,
                     u'tariffDetails': {},
                     u'tariffType': u'Single rate',
                     u'timeDefinition': u'Local time'}],
  u'offerFuelType': 0},
 {u'isChecked': False,
  u'isClosed': False,
  u'offerDetails': [{u'basePrice': 1080,
                     u'conditionalPrice': 1080,
                     u'contractLength': [u'None'],
                     u'contractLengthCount': 1,
                     u'coolingOffPeriod': 10,
                     u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0,
                     u'exitFee': [0],
                     u'exitFeeCount': 1,
                     u'fullDiscountedPrice': 720,
                     u'greenPower': 0,
                     u'greenpowerAmount': 0,
                     u'greenpowerChargeType': None,
                     u'hasIncentive': False,
                     u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': True,
                     u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000',
                     u'isDirectDebitOnly': False,
                     u'isPartDual': False,
                     u'isTouOffer': True,
                     u'offerId': u'GLO41009MR',
                     u'offerKey': u'7642',
                     u'offerName': u'GLO SWITCH',
                     u'offerType': u'Market offer',
                     u'retailerId': u'31206',
                     u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/globird.jpg',
                     u'retailerName': u'GloBird Energy',
                     u'retailerPhone': u'(03) 8560 4199',
                     u'retailerUrl': u'http://www.globirdenergy.com.au/switchon/',
                     u'solarType': None,
                     u'tariffDetails': {},
                     u'tariffType': u'Time of use',
                     u'timeDefinition': u'Local time'}],
  u'offerFuelType': 0}]
```

Which should match what you see on the page when you click the `"DISCOUNTED PRICE"` filter button.

For the normal view it seems to be ordered by `conditionalPrice` or `basePrice`, again pulling just the two first values should match what you see on the webpage:

```
 base = sorted(js, key=lambda d: d["offerDetails"][0]["conditionalPrice"])

from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(base[:2])

[{u'isChecked': False,
  u'isClosed': False,
  u'offerDetails': [{u'basePrice': 740,
                     u'conditionalPrice': 740,
                     u'contractLength': [u'None'],
                     u'contractLengthCount': 1,
                     u'coolingOffPeriod': 0,
                     u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0,
                     u'exitFee': [0],
                     u'exitFeeCount': 0,
                     u'fullDiscountedPrice': 740,
                     u'greenPower': 0,
                     u'greenpowerAmount': 0,
                     u'greenpowerChargeType': None,
                     u'hasIncentive': False,
                     u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': False,
                     u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000',
                     u'isDirectDebitOnly': False,
                     u'isPartDual': False,
                     u'isTouOffer': False,
                     u'offerId': u'NEX42694SR',
                     u'offerKey': u'9092',
                     u'offerName': u'Citpower Single Rate Residential',
                     u'offerType': u'Standing offer',
                     u'retailerId': u'35726',
                     u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/nextbusinessenergy.jpg',
                     u'retailerName': u'Next Business Energy Pty Ltd',
                     u'retailerPhone': u'1300 466 398',
                     u'retailerUrl': u'http://www.nextbusinessenergy.com.au/',
                     u'solarType': None,
                     u'tariffDetails': {},
                     u'tariffType': u'Single rate',
                     u'timeDefinition': u'Local time'}],
  u'offerFuelType': 0},
 {u'isChecked': False,
  u'isClosed': False,
  u'offerDetails': [{u'basePrice': 780,
                     u'conditionalPrice': 780,
                     u'contractLength': [u'None'],
                     u'contractLengthCount': 1,
                     u'coolingOffPeriod': 0,
                     u'estimatedSolarCredit': 0,
                     u'exitFee': [0],
                     u'exitFeeCount': 0,
                     u'fullDiscountedPrice': 780,
                     u'greenPower': 0,
                     u'greenpowerAmount': 0,
                     u'greenpowerChargeType': None,
                     u'hasIncentive': False,
                     u'hasPayOnTimeDiscount': False,
                     u'intrinsicGreenpowerPercentage': u'0.0000',
                     u'isDirectDebitOnly': False,
                     u'isPartDual': False,
                     u'isTouOffer': False,
                     u'offerId': u'NEX42699SR',
                     u'offerKey': u'9090',
                     u'offerName': u'Citpower Residential Flexible Pricing',
                     u'offerType': u'Standing offer',
                     u'retailerId': u'35726',
                     u'retailerImageUrl': u'img/retailers/big/nextbusinessenergy.jpg',
                     u'retailerName': u'Next Business Energy Pty Ltd',
                     u'retailerPhone': u'1300 466 398',
                     u'retailerUrl': u'http://www.nextbusinessenergy.com.au/',
                     u'solarType': None,
                     u'tariffDetails': {},
                     u'tariffType': u'Flexible Pricing',
                     u'timeDefinition': u'Local time'}],
  u'offerFuelType': 0}]
```

You can see all the json returned in firebug console if you click the `https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/service/offers` get entry then hit r*esponse*:

[image]

You should be able to pull each field that you want from that.

The output actually has a few extras results which you don't see on the page unless you toggle the tou button below:

[image]

You can filter those from the results so you exactly match the default output or give an option to include with a helper function:

```
def order_by(l, k, is_tou=False):
    if not is_tou:
        filt = filter(lambda x: not x["offerDetails"][0]["isTouOffer"], l)
        return sorted(filt, key=lambda d: d["offerDetails"][0][k])
    return sorted(l, key=lambda d: d["offerDetails"][0][k])

import json
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post(sub_url, data=form1)
    r = (s.get("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire"))
    s.post("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/energy_questionnaire/submit",
           data=form2)
    js = s.get("https://compare.switchon.vic.gov.au/service/offers").json()["offersList"]
    by_price = by_discount(js, "conditionalPrice", False)

print(by_price[:3)
```

If you check the output you will see origin energy third with a price of 840 in  the results with the switch on or 860 for AGL when it is off, you can apply the same to the discount output:

[image]

[image]

The regular output also seems to be ordered by *conditionalPrice* if you check the source the two js functions that get called for ordering are:

```
 ng-click="changeSortingField('conditionalPrice')"
 ng-click="changeSortingField('fullDiscountedPrice')"
```

So that should now definitely completely match the site output.

Comment: Excellent answer ! thank you ! I will wait for an R answer but definitely I will accept this one!

Comment: @agstudy, no worries, I have no clue when it comes to R so I am afraid  I won't be much use in that department.